# How to Login with Enter Keypress JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I am trying to login with the below code when pressing Enter Keyboard button. The form is placed in the body tag with class `loginpg`. After pressing enter I am getting alert message & something is happening but I am not logging into pages in sales force platform. What am I missing?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      alert('You pressed enter!');
      $('.loginpg form').submit();
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: the default behaviour of pressing enter on input inside form is to submit the form. I'm really not sure what are you attempting here???

Comment: Put the `input` inside a `form` and you get this behaviour by default.

Comment: `"something happening"` - Maybe you can be more descriptive than that?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: @David - disappointing. I can see it clearly. It is not logging him in ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your login button must be a `type="submit"`.

And the `<input>` button must be inside `<form></form>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
$('.loginpg form').submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

I think you can try without `return false;`

`return false;` is stopping page redirection.

Comment: Why would that stop a submit you just called?

Comment: when you submit something, page start redirect and after you call "return false;" it's stopping redirect process

Comment: Not it is not. That is untrue. If you return false in the submit handler, the form is not submitted, but this is not the case here